# Flutter pubspec.yaml ,audioplayer not working

Tags: flutter, dependencies, audio-player

I started flutter these days. I'm trying to make an audio drum app.So I added the dependencies to file pubspec.yaml
audioplayers: ^0.19.1
But when I click 'pub get' I get this error.

Cannot create link, path = 'C:\src\flutter\flutter.pub-cache_temp\dir1b96d188\ios\Classes\AudioplayersPlugin.h' (OS Error: Required privilege is not provided by client.
, errno = 1314)
pub get failed (66; , errno = 1314))

Comment: what about your flutter sdk version?

Comment: Flutter 2.4.0-4.0.pre

Comment: you will try with null safety audioplayers:, because you used dev channel latest build

Comment: thanks for your helps.now i install new package https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayer
but no sound from the app

Answer (score 0):

Use audioplayers 0.20.1
Then go to .../android/buildgradle and change ext.kotlin_version to '1.4.32'
That worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).